# Microscopy: aperture matching and Huygen's principle

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, microscopy

I have repeatedly read that the maximum spatial resolution of a microscope occurs when the aperture of the objective and condenser are the same. However, I don't understand why.

The resolution is defined by the numerical aperture (i.e. angular acceptance), but Huygen's principle implies that the sample is an ensemble of point sources emitting spherical waves. These spherical waves are presumably from 0->2Pi, in which case the NA of the condenser shouldn't have any influence at all (since it can't increase the range of angles emitted by the sample beyond 2Pi).

Is there something I'm missing here?

I've scoured textbooks like Hecht, Goodman etc, but I can't find a detailed discussion of the role of the condenser.

Cheers,
Hugh

Comment: Is it simply that resolution is limited by the "limiting aperture" and that when they are the same neither is "too good for the job"?